# Decomposition of a reducible representation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I got completely stumbled upon the following question. Let's suppose that I'm given a certain representation of a Lie algebra and want to find its decomposition into irreducible blocks (not only formulae like $2\otimes2=1\oplus3$, but also the explicit change of basis). I know what I should do in two other cases: a) in case of the finite groups I should have calculated the characters; b) in case of tensor products I should have found highest-weight states. But here I'm completely stuck and don't even understand what to do.

The question arose from the following problem i tried to solve unsuccessfully. 3 matrices $G^i$ (with $\sigma^i$ being Pauli $\sigma$-matrices):
$$
G^1 = i \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\sigma_3\\ \sigma_3& 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad G^2 = i \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \sigma_1\\ -\sigma_1& 0\end{pmatrix}, \quad G^3 = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_2&0\\ 0&\sigma_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

form an $su(2)$-representation after certain rescalings: $[G^i, G^j] = -2 i \epsilon^{ijk}G^k$. They answer (which I could not obtain) is that they, actually, form a reducible representation with the following form
$$
U^\dagger G^i U = \begin{pmatrix} -\sigma^i & 0\\ 0& -\sigma^i\end{pmatrix}
$$

achieved with the help of unitary transformation
$$ U =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & i & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0 & i \\ i & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

I am more interested in understanding the general situation and whether there are some algorythms to do this, but will equally appreciate the explanation of what happened in the explicit example.

**Update**. Not sure if it's helpful, but in the particular example the following route seems possible. To determine the structure of representation: one could simply find the eigenvalues of the matrices $G^i$, which turn out to be $(1,1,-1,-1)$, from which it's pretty much clear that it's $2\oplus2$. Then I tried diagonalizing $G^3$, since it can correspond to $diag(-\sigma_3,-\sigma_3)$, after some juggling with rows permutation I almost obtained the required decomposition, but not yet: there still is a residual similarity transformation.